# $PA \vdash \forall x(S(S(S...(S(x))...))) \neq \bar{0} $

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

I sign $\bar{k}$ the elements in $\mathbb{N}$ model for $PA$, and I use $\neq$ instead of $\neg(a=b)$ andd $S^n(x)$ as $S(S(...S(x))))$ just for convenience.

I was trying to show $PA\vdash \forall x(S^n(x)\neq \bar{0})$, using Peano's induction axiom, with $\varphi(x) = S^n (x) \neq \bar{0}$ and by trying to use a (regular) induction over $n$ , means start from $PA\vdash S(x)\neq \bar{0}$ (which as long as I know is an axiom) and then assume $S^k(x)\neq 0 $ for $k<n$

But I don't see how to proceed from this point, casue when trying to use the induction axiom, I couldn't find a way to apply the induction assumption.

$\forall x(\forall y(y<x)\rightarrow\ S(y)\neq \bar{0})\rightarrow S(x)\neq \bar{0})\rightarrow\forall x(S^n(x)\neq \bar{0})$

Sure that any other way to prove it will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this just a specialization of the axiom $(\forall x)(S(x) \ne \bar 0)$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm sorry but I don't understand, what do you mean by **specialization** of the axiom?

Comment: "Specialization" here means taking the statement in @DanielSchepler's comment, which is about all values of $x$, and putting in a value for $x$.  In this case, the value you want to put in is $S^{n-1}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be a model of PA. Since PA proves $\forall x (S(x) \neq 0)$, then let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $M$ and let $a = S^{n-1}(x)$. So then $M \models S(a) \neq 0$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, this means $M \models \forall x (S^{n}(x) \neq 0)$. Since this statement is true for every model $M$, by the completeness theorem it is provable from PA.

Comment: I don't understand why one can take $S^{n-1} (x^M)$ for any element $x$ in $W^M$ , cause correct me if I'm wrong but a Model for PA axioms doesn't have to be infinite.

Comment: First of all, S is a function with domain M, so for any element of M, S(x) is an element of M, and so is S(S(x)). Secondly, I don't know what you're trying to say by the statement "axioms doesn't have to be infinite."

Comment: All right, thanks, I understand now. It doesn't matter but I meant that: a model for PA doesn't have to be infinite.

Comment: You can prove that a model of PA must be infinite. If it were finite (say it has $n$ elements), and $S(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$, then the range of $S$ has at most $n - 1$ elements, and therefore $S$ cannot be an injection, which contradicts one of the axioms.